# LM386L does not amplify the microphone signal

Tags: amplifier, speakers, lm386, condenser-microphone

I've encountered a problem. I recently bought a condenser microphone and I wanted to have some fun, so that if I said something into the microphone, I'd hear myself in the small 8 Ohm 0.5W speaker.

I have used an LM386L amplifier and there seems to be no sound at the output. It seems like it's not amplifying anything at all. Here's the circuit on the breadboard:

[image: photo of breadboard]

[image]

What I have basically done is:

- I took an output from the microphone and put it on pin 3 of LM386L.
- Pins 2 & 4 are all connected to ground.
- I used 10 uF between pin 1 and 8 to obtain a proper gain.
- On pin 7 I used another 10 uF capacitor.
- Pin 5 represents the output of the amplifier, where I put 100pF ceramic capacitor in parallel to the 600uF electrolytic capacitor and 8 Ohm speaker to get rid of all unwanted frequencies. 600uF capacitor should get rid of any DC voltage.

When I talk into the microphone, nothing happens although when I connect it to oscilloscope, I see a voltage, so the microphone works. I'm powering it with 5V.

If anyone knows the solution, please help me. And do not mind the soldered pins on the female jack.

Comment: Does it amplify anything from other sources? What powers the microphone? Can you please draw this as a schematic?

Comment: Even with an AC short between pins 1 and 8, the gain is still only 200, which is probably not enough to take mic level all the way to speaker level.

Comment: @DaveTweed, well.. something weird happened.. I hardly tapped on the top of the microphone and I got some noise from the speaker.. so I think, as you say, it's not enough to amplify it to that level.. Any idea how to boost it more?

Comment: If it's an electret mic, have you biased it correctly? ( 4K7 to +9V will probably do, and a DC blocking cap to the amp) See any "electret mic" circuit for details

Comment: @BrianDrummond but it's not

Comment: Please add the full mic circuit to the rest of the circuit you have already.

Comment: "but it's not" - so what is it exactly?

Comment: @BruceAbbott, it's a condenser microphone

Comment: @Aaron, you mean like.. what's inside, or what? I have it directly connected on the pin 3.

Comment: [Condenser microphones require a bias voltage.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microphone#Condenser)

Comment: @MerryGR, So you are saying that the mic only has one wire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling "condenser microphone circuit" shows lots of schematics that have three things yours is missing

As does the image in this [Question on biasing a condenser mic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/94557/calculate-the-appropriate-bias-voltage-and-resistor-of-a-condenser-microphone)

- Where does the other side of your mic connect?
- What is your biasing?
- Where is your DC blocking cap?

[image]

I've used the LM386 to power 8Ω woofer speakers, and you will hear audio, once you have your mic set up correctly.

Comment: thanks, I will give it a try tomorrow.